definition and properties of a tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^d$
Is this a true definition of a tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^d$?
A tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^d$ space is a geometric solid defined by the convex hull of  $d+1$ affinely independent points in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Equivalently, a tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be described as the polytope formed by the convex combination of $d+1$ affinely independent points.
Properties:

A tetrahedron in   $\mathbb{R}^d$  has $d+1$ vertices.
It consists of  $C(d,2)$ triangular faces, each defined by a subset of three vertices.
The edges of the tetrahedron are formed by connecting pairs of vertices.
The $d$-dimensional volume of a tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be calculated using appropriate determinant operations.


I think the term "$n$-simplex" might be better than "tetrahedron", which people usually reserve for the case of $\mathbb R^3$.

@krm2233 Thank you. If I call this shape an $n$-simplex, do the definition and properties I outlined indicate a tetrahedron similar to what we have in 3D?

It's much nicer and more natural to define an $n$-simplex ($n=1$ line segment, $n=2$ filled triangle, $n = 3$ solid tetrahedron, etc.) as a convex subset of $(n+1)$-dimensional space. In coordinates $t_0, t_1, \dots, t_n$, we require each $t_i \geq 0$ and the sum $t_0 + t_1 + \cdots + t_n = 1$. Because of the single affine linear constraint equation, its dimension is clearly $(n+1) - 1 = n$, as desired. Try sketching these for $n = 1$ and $n = 2$.

@SammyBlack nice tip. thanks

Have a look here, but try not to get overwhelmed. There's a lot of math built around simplices.

@MamaD: I should have been clearer about the relationship between $n$-simplex and tetrahedron -- the latter is a $3$-simplex, and in general an $n$-simplex is the convex hull of any collection of $(n+1)$ points in general positive in an affine $n$-space. In terms of the definition and properties, your first three points are special cases of the fact that an $n$-simplex has $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ faces of dimension $k$, which are each $k$-simplices.

@SammyBlack Wow you saved me. I come from Computer Science and I had a problem with the calculation of $n-$simplex volume. Your link was very helpful. thank you so much

@krm2233 Excuse me if I ask you a stupid question, I come from Computer Science, not mathematics. Is this true that a $3$-simplex is a tetrahedron?

@MamaD yes, a tetrahedron is just the convex hull of 4 points in $\mathbb R^3$ which do not all lie in a plane.


In $\mathbb R^n$, an $n$-simplex $\Delta_n$ is the convex hull of $(n+1)$ points $\{a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$:
$$
\Delta_n = \{\sum_{i=0}^n t_i a_i: \forall i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}, t_i \geq 0,  \sum_{i=0}^n t_i =1\}.
$$
where, if we define $v_i$ for $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ by the identities $a_i = a_0 +v_i$ we require $\det(v_1|\ldots|v_n)\neq 0$. Note that
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
\sum_{i=0}^n t_ia_i = t_0 a_0+ \sum_{i=1}^n t_i(a_0+v_i) = (\sum_{i=0}^n t_i)a_0 +\sum_{i=1}^n t_iv_i  = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n t_i v_i
$$
so that we have $\Delta_n = \{a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n t_i v_i: \forall i, t_i \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^n t_i \leq 1\}$.
[Alternatively, in some contexts, the convex hull of any $(n+1)$ points in $\mathbb R^n$ is said to be an $n$-simplex, with the ones which have $\det(v_1|\ldots|v_n)=0$ referred to as "singular" or "degenerate" simplices.]

Any $(k+1)$ element subset of $\{a_0,\ldots,a_n\}$ has as its convex hull a $k$-simplex, and so $\Delta_n$ has $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ "faces" of dimension $k$, each of which is a $k$-simplex -- e.g., when $n=3$ this says $\Delta_3$ has $4$ vertices and faces and $6$ edges.

The "$n$-volume" of an $n$-simplex is equal to $\frac{1}{n!} \det(v_1|\ldots|v_n)$: if we let $P_n$ denote the $n$-dimensional parallelpiped
$$
P_n = \{a_0 +\sum_{i=1}^n s_iv_i: s_i \in [0,1], \forall i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}
$$
(so that $P_n$ has $2^n$ vertices: $\{a_0+ \sum_{i \in J} v_i: \forall J \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}\}$), then, essentially by definition, $\mathrm{vol}(P_n) = \det(v_1|\ldots|v_n)$. Thus we would like to understand why
$$
\frac{\mathrm{vol}(\Delta_n)}{\mathrm{vol}(P_n)} = \frac{1}{n!}
$$

Given a point $p = a_0+\sum_{i=1}^n s_i v_i \in P_n$, unless $\vec{s}=(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ lies on one of the $\binom{n}{2}$ hyperplanes $H_{ij} = \{\vec{s}: v_i = v_j\}$ (where $1\leq i \neq j \leq n$) then there is a unique permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $(s_{\sigma(1)}>s_{\sigma(2)}>\ldots>s_{\sigma(n)})$. But then we claim that $p$ lies in the simplex with vertices
$$
\{a_0, a_0+v_{\sigma(1)}, a_0+v_{\sigma_1}+v_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,a_0 + v_{\sigma(1)}+\ldots v_{\sigma(n)}\}.
$$
Indeed if we let $w_i = \sum_{j=1}^{i} v_{\sigma(j)}$ then $p = a_0+ \sum_{i=1}^n (s_i-s_{i+1})w_i$, where we set $s_{n+1}=0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n(s_i-s_{i+1}) = s_{\sigma(1)} \in [0,1]$. Comparing with $(\dagger)$ above establishes the claim.

It follows that $P_n$ is the union of $n!$ many $n$-simplices -- indeed this exhibits $P_n$ as a simplicial complex, and each of these simplices  can be obtained from our original simplex by "shearing" transformations, which are volume preserving (this claim I have to just quote and use as a black--box) and hence all of the $n!$ simplices should have the same volume, and thus they all have volume $\frac{1}{n!} \det(v_1|\ldots|v_n)$.


